# if modified date is same as current date then it will copy one file to a location

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file that should do as follows:

1. It will check the file's modified date in one location
2. It will compare the modified date with the current date.
3. If the two dates are same then it will copy the file to a location
4. if the modified date is not equal to the current date then it will echo that the file is not updated.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
@echo off

set currentDate=%date:~-10%
SET filename="C:\users\ani\desktop\IMP\RetailEmp.txt"


FOR %%X IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tX
pause
if %filedatetime:~0,10% == %currentDate% 
pause
(
ROBOCOPY C:\Users\ANI\Desktop\IMP  C:\downloads\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%,RetailEmp.txt

pause

)
pause
if not %filedatetime:~0,10% == %currentDate%
(echo file not updated
pause
)
Exit /b 0
```

But the batch script is not working. My guess is that it must be bypassing the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting `(`has to be on the same line as the `if`:

```
if %filedatetime:~0,10% == %currentDate% 
pause
(
ROBOCOPY C:\Users\ANI\Desktop\IMP  C:\downloads\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%,RetailEmp.txt
pause
)
```

should look like:

```
if %filedatetime:~0,10% == %currentDate% (
  pause
  ROBOCOPY C:\Users\ANI\Desktop\IMP  C:\downloads\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%,RetailEmp.txt
  pause
)
```

Comment: excellent. It works. Thanks a lot for the valuable time and answer:):) appreciate it